# Python load list in list from text file

Tags: python

I want to load list in list from text file. I went through many examples but no solution. This is what I want to do
I am new bee to python

```
def main()
    mainlist = [[]]
    infile = open('listtxt.txt','r')
    for line in infile:
        mainlist.append(line)

    infile.close()

    print mainlist

`[[],['abc','def', 1],['ghi','jkl',2]]`
```

however what I want is something like this

```
[['abc','def',1],['ghi','jkl',2]]
```

my list contains

```
'abc','def',1
'ghi','jkl',2
'mno','pqr',3
```

what I want is when I access the list 
`print mainlist[0]`
should return

```
'abc','def',1
```

any help will be highly appreciated
Thanks,

Comment: For your expected output : `[['abc','def',1],['ghi','jkl',2]]`, `print  mainlist[0]` will return `['abc','def',1]`

Comment: everything is fine, you just have an extra bracket to start your mainlist! change `mainlist = [[]]` to `mainlist = []` and then `print mainlist[0]` will return `['abc','def',1]`

Answer (score 15):

It seems to me that you could do this as:

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open('listtxt.txt') as f:
    mainlist = [list(literal_eval(line)) for line in f]
```

This is the easist way to make sure that the types of the elements are preserved.  e.g. a line like:

```
"foo","bar",3
```

will be transformed into 2 strings and an integer.  Of course, the lines themselves need to be formatted as a python tuple... and this probably isn't the *fastest* approach due to it's generality and simplicity.

Comment: This is it, script above worked. The way I wanted it this is perfect,
Thank-you very much
BTW same thing I could have done very quickly using array in C# or delphi etc.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like this.

```
mainlist = []
infile = open('listtxt.txt','r')
for line in infile:
    mainlist.append(line.strip().split(','))

infile.close()

print mainlist
```

Comment: out put of above ["'abc','def',1", "'ghi','jkl',2", "'mno','pqr',3"]

Comment: No it's not, split return a list. infile = ["'abc','def',1", "'ghi','jkl',2", "'mno','pqr',3"]
I tried it, the output is [["'abc'", "'def'", '1'], ["'ghi'", "'jkl'", '2'], ["'mno'", "'pqr'", '3']]

Answer (score 2):

You're initializing `mainlist` with an empty list as first element, rather than as an empty list itself.  Change:

```
mainlist = [[]]
```

to

```
mainlist = []
```

Comment: funny thing is when I create list manually everything work fine
def main():
    mainlist = [['abc','def',1],['ghi','jkl',2]]

    print mainlist[0][0]
     output is 'abc'
why samething not happen when I load list from text file
It seems I am missing some point

Answer (score 2):

I'd try something like:

```
with open('listtxt.txt', 'r') as f:
    mainlist = [line for line in f]
```

Comment: out put of above ["'abc','def',1", "'ghi','jkl',2", "'mno','pqr',3"]
why there are double quotes

Comment: @user2330294 your input has quotes which are part of the string

Answer (score 1):

```
mainlist = []
infile = open('filelist.txt', 'r')
for line in infile:
    line = line.replace('\n', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'", "").replace(' ', '')
    mainlist.append(line.split(','))
infile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `json` module like below (Python 3.x):

```
import json

def main()
    mainlist = [[]]
    infile = open('listtxt.txt','r')

    data = json.loads(infile.read())

    mainlist.append(data)

    infile.close()

    print(mainlist)

>>> [[],['abc','def', 1],['ghi','jkl',2]]
```

Your "listtxt.txt" file should look like this:

```
[["abc","def", 1],["ghi","jkl",2]]
```

To export your list, do this:

```
def export():
        with open("listtxt.txt", 'w') as export_file:
             json.dump(mainlist, export_file)
```

JSON module can load lists, found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#saving-structured-data-with-json)

Answer (score 0):

I had a list of surnames - one per line - in a text file which I wanted to read into a list. Here's how I did it (remembering to strip the newline character).

```
surnames = [name.strip("\n") for name in open("surnames.txt", "r")]
```